# automatically run program when computer boots

Tags: c#

I have designed an application which should greet the user when he turns on his computer.The program works well on my pc ,but when I transferred the .exe file of the program on my brother's computer it doesn't work meaning that "it doesn't work automatically when the pc boots"...How can I overcome this problem?? this is my code

Note:the program runs well if i executed it manually,but I want it to work automatically.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.IO;

namespace helloMSG
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    RegistryKey reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        reg.SetValue("My app", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
```

}
`

Comment: Does the program work at all on your brother's PC? Which version of .Net does he have installed?

Comment: Where's the program that greets the user? The code you have appears to be related to reading the registry!

Comment: the program runs well if i executed it manually,but i want it to work automatically.

Comment: @ Lee: I put the great message as a label on the form which appears to the user

Comment: So why are you dealing with the registry in there?

Comment: @ lee:  dealing with the registry to make it works automatically

Answer (score 1):

If you want the program to start after Windows has booted then copy the executeable to the Startup directory:

1. Click the Start button Picture of the Start button , click All Programs, right-click the Startup folder, and then click Open.
2. Open the location that contains the item you want to create a shortcut to.
3. Right-click the item, and then click Create Shortcut. The new shortcut appears in the same location as the original item.
4. Drag the shortcut into the Startup folder.

Here is the source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7.

If the program does not run on your friends PC, then make sure the .NET version is correct.  There may be more information in Event Viewer telling you what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The target computer should match requirements, at least the correct .net version should be installed and other dependencies, if any.Besides admin privileges might be required since you are writing to registry. 
One more thing. You really don't need a winforms application for that. A Console one should do.

Comment: @ Miha Markic:it has all requirements and the program runs well if i executed it manually,but i want it to work automatically

Comment: So, what is it? You don't know how to set it to run at boot or it is set but doesn't run?

Comment: I don't know how to set it to run at boot

Comment: Try this http://lifehacker.com/5829375/how-to-start-a-program-automatically-when-your-computer-boots or Task scheduler.

Comment: Also Close and Dispose that RegistryKey you are using after you done with it.